# How should questions about Cantor space and Cantor cubes be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There exists a tag called [cantor-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantor-set). Based on the [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1354975/revisions) of the [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/cantor-set/info) it is about [Cantor ternary set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and also about generalization to [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). Both of them have very similar constructions and are subsets of $[0,1]$.

It is well known that, as a topological space, the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the [Cantor space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space) $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ or $\{0,1\}^\omega$, i.e., countable power of 2-point discrete space. And this space can be generalized to [Cantor cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_cube) $\{0,1\}^A$, where $A$ can be set of arbitrary cardinality.

IIRC I have seen a few questions about the Cantor space with (cantor-set) tag. (Of course, in some cases a question can be about both the Cantor set and Cantor space. For example, questions asking about proof that they are homeomorphic. So sometimes there is no clear division line between questions about the Cantor set and questions about the Cantor space.) I don't recall whether I have seen a questions about Cantor cubes tagged like this.

So the questions are:

- Should we have some tag for Cantor cubes (including the Cantor space). (In a sense [the-baire-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-baire-space) tag can be considered as a kind of precedence, since it is a tag about the space $\omega^\omega$, which is similar to $2^\omega$. Some discussion about this tag can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/the-baire-space-tag).)
- If the answer to the preceding question is yes, then the other question arises: Should Cantor cubes be in the same tag sa Cantor set, or should these be two separate tags. (If the decision is that they belong into the same tag, then we should probably clarify this in the tag-info. And synonyms [cantor-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantor-space) $\to$ [cantor-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantor-set) and [cantor-cubes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantor-cubes) $\to$ [cantor-set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cantor-set) would probably help correct tagging.)

I will also add a link to a recent [conversation concerning tagging questions about this topics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/tags-for-cantor-set-cantor-space-cantor-cube) in chat.

And it is probably also worth mentioning that there was a [suggestion to remove (cantor-set) tag completely](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/20374#20374), but results of the voting on this post did not show much support of that proposal. (However, there were not too many users who voted on that, at the moment the score is 1 with two upvotes and one downvote.)

Comment: Using [tag:cantor-set] seems fine. It signals what the basic object is, or at least what sort of object one is to find discussed in the question. If needed, the tag can be edited to include variants so it does not appear to be exclusively about the standard ternary set.

Comment: I have edited the tag [tag:cantor-set] in that fashion.

Answer (score 5):

Probably most questions involving Cantor cubes could be tagged using a tag saying what the question is *really* about ...

general-topology
metric-spaces
measure-theory
dynamical-systems
cardinals

Comment: What about a question not just _involving_ a Cantor cube, but strictly _about_ a Cantor cube, such as [Is $2^{\frak{c}}$ separable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985539/8348) or [What does $\text{cl}(\text{im}(e_\mathbb{N}))\subseteq 2^{2^{\mathbb{N}}}$ look like?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1986017). Sure they are in [tag:general-topology], but this tag is also one of the 10 largest tags on the site, so it doesn't really help in later finding such questions.

Comment: I agree with @GEdgar. In those cases, where the problem is precisely about the cantor cube, then I think that using the cantor-set tag is fine, but would discourage the use of such a tag in topological problems that use it.